# How can I delete Ubuntu and install windows xp (.exe version)

Tags: installation, laptop, compaq

What my problem is, is that I want to install windows xp on my laptop where ubuntu is installed on, I cannot run the disc because it is an .exe and you can't run that on ubuntu. I tried several things and searched for like an hour on the internet, I hope someone knows how to help me.

Sorry for my bad english, I am dutch.

[edit]
The answer wich some of you linked is not an answer to my question because I have a black screen after I try to boot with the disc

Comment: how is ubuntu installed? is ubuntu installed by wubi or installed by disc/usb or was it pre-installed (bought your laptop with ubuntu on it)?

Comment: some time ago my uncle did that for me after the laptop was running terribly slow (probably had a virus), so I don't know. I already tried to run the disc from boot setup thing, but that I got a black screen after that

Comment: Also remember that support for XP will be terminated next year (April I think) by Microsoft. Out of curiosity why do you want to move from Ubuntu to XP?

Comment: Because I have an upgrade from xp/vista to win7, I dont have the orginial boot disc for win7 from the laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to boot from the disc, so the disc with XP on would need to be in the disc drive when you start up your laptop, and then you should get on-screen instructions to install XP.

If this is causing a black screen that you mentioned in your comment, this is unlikely to be due to Ubuntu and more likely to do with the disc being corrupted somehow (or your disc drive not working properly). If you believe the disc drive is acting up, you can try cleaning  the laser lens. If its the XP disc itself, there isn't much that can be done to save it unfortunately, as far as I know.

Comment: I can open the disc on my desktop... and I can see the disc on the menu but as I said not run the .exe

Comment: That suggests to me that the disc drive is working. You wouldn't want to run the .exe from inside Ubuntu anyway, but just because you can see what's on the disc doesn't necessarily mean the disc is not corrupted in some way, which is the only reason I can see for you getting this black screen when trying to boot from the disc (I assume since you are getting the black screen that it is at least trying to boot from the disc)

Comment: I think youre right, ive still got some windows keys lying around here somewhere, I'll ask around for the discs thanks